# How can I fix a gradient text error that appears only on iPhone?

Tags: html, css

I'm building up my website, but I got troubles with this code only on iphone.

I want some gradient text into Titles, so i used a "h1" tag with "span" in it, and with css i put on some gradient on the span tag.
Everything's working fine, but on iphone when that "span" text goes on a new line, it disappears.
I tried using rgba code on css, but nothing.

```html
<h1>I <span style="color: #00bbff;">usually help</span> people.</h1>
```

and the css code is

```css
h1 span {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,255,238,1), rgba(0,187,255,1));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Everything's working on computer or smartphone, but on iphone when "help" goes on a new line, it becomes transparent.

Any tip?

Comment: I think you need to add `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,255,238,1), rgba(0,187,255,1));` as well.

Comment: Hi, that's not the problem :( The code works fine on mobile and desktop, the problem is only on iphone.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that safari needed the -webkit specification for linear-gradients. I saw that you added it for the text fill color, and thought safari was only picking up the transparency.

Comment: Come to think of it, I think the newest specification for safari is something like  `-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), to(255,250,240,1));` --- As an example.

Comment: By using this code

`h1 span {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), to(255,250,240,1));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}`

nothing's working :/ no mobile or desktop

Comment: Then I am at a loss, my friend. Sorry I couldn't be more help. I don't have an iphone or safari to test - all I can do is "fake" an iphone with Chrome dev tools.

Comment: don't worry, thank you so much btw for your time!

Comment: I have same problem!